# ORDER BY two dates mysql query

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I am going to give order in query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_report` ORDER BY `cancel_date`, `pur_date`
```

But its not working could you please check what is wrong in this query because its not ordering dates?

pur_date type is date and cancel_date type is text so is it issue ? I can't change its type.

I echo a different think like:

```
if(cancel_date != ''){
$transection_date = cancel_date;
}
else {
$transection_date = pur_date;
}
```

Comment: Now we need to guess what `cancel_date` example values are or what?

Comment: cancel_date example values are just like a date like: 2012-05-30 but its type is text instead of date in mysql

Comment: date in such format are sorting friendly and work fine. There is some other issues perhaps. Please provide as much details about your db and how you're working with it as you can

Comment: Here is the query what I am using:
     
SELECT * FROM `sales_report` WHERE `pur_date` BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30' ORDER BY `pur_date`, `cancel_date`
    
and here is what I have echo I echo $transection_date and its explained in my question above. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `sales_report`
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE(`cancel_date`, '%Y-%m-%d'), `pur_date`;
```

As **zerkms** mentioned in comments: You should use format specifiers, dependent of your text values in `cancel_date` column.

Comment: If it's in `'%Y-%m-%d'` format - you don't need to convert it into date, it will work as it is

Comment: I overreacted, it's legit if OP could get that they need to specify their format, +1

Comment: @SonyG could you supply `cancel_date` sample values, please ?

Comment: cancel_date values are same like a date in pur_date 2013-05-30 but cancel_date type is text.

Comment: Well, it should be... I've tested it. Try to wrap it with `TRIM()` like `STR_TO_DATE(TRIM(cancel_date), '%Y-%m-%d')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, CAST(`cancel_date` as DateTime) cancelDate 
FROM `sales_report`
ORDER BY `cancelDate`, `purDate`
```

This should work

Comment: `'cancelDate'` - it's a string literal